# TYPO3: I need to add typoscript lines to object with a custom extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, data-processing

I added an image selection to a content element in my main extension with a custom extension, this field should now be added in the `dataProcessing` that is performed in the main extension, but it should be added in the custom extension :

```
tt_content.t3bs_carousel < lib.contentElement
tt_content.t3bs_carousel {
    templateName = Carousel
    templateRootPaths {
        9 = {$plugin.tx_t3bs_main.view.templateRootPath}Content/
        8 = EXT:t3bs_main/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/
    }
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
            references.fieldName = assets
            as = assets
        }
        // this 20 should be added by the custom extension
        20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        20 {
            references.fieldName = tx_t3bs_portrait_image
            as = portrait
        }
        90 >
    }
}
```

if I safe this in the main extension it works, I cannot find a typoscript that makes me add it in my custom extension, I tried to insert the entire object (since my custom extension is loaded after the main), then also only the missing part that needs to be added:

```
tt_content.t3bs_carousel.dataProcessing {
    20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    20 {
        references.fieldName = tx_t3bs_portrait_image
        as = portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having any details to your "custom extension" it's hard to help... Is the TypoScript file of your custom extension included?

Comment: What would you need to suggest how to go about?

Comment: was this what you asked for ?

Comment: if the loading order of these extensions is clear you only need to make sure, that the typoscript of both extensions is included - and in the correct order. (static includes may be in other order than the extensions). inspect with "Template Analyzer".

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ the template analyzer gives me the typoscript of both extensions, but I still cannot see why the code I try to add to tt_content.t3bs_carousel is not taken

Comment: Is it `tt_content.t3bs_carousel < lib.contentElement`? Or is it `tt_content.t3bs_carousel =< lib.contentElement`? Big difference!

Comment: the order might be important. the template analyzer shows the order of evaluated typoscript. maybe the detail is set first and erased by the setting of the global. a ölater `tt_content.t3bs_carousel < lib.contentElement` will erase a former `tt_content.t3bs_carousel.dataProcessing.20 = ...`

Comment: @StefanPadbergS I noticed that too in the documentation ... it's only < which is working ... I just cannot override it with my custom extention